# Reduce Bandwidth on a cisco router (Cisco 877)

Tags: cisco, bandwidth, network-speed

PS:Sorry for my english i'm french so i'll try to write the best as I can.

I looking since a few weeks now for a command to reduce the bandwidth on a cisco router. I done try a lot off command and when i try to see my speed upload and download is still the same. I would like to know how can i reduce the bandwidth i've got a connection off 512Kbits and i want to increase it to 256kbits on all the port.

Thanks

Comment: The question is a little unclear... Are you trying to cap each built-in switchport on an 877 to max of 256kb/s in/out?

Comment: yes i want to limit the internet speed on all the ports at 256kbits and my connection is 512kbits connection.